# Customizing Insert/Edit FormView for Entity Dynamic data framework

Tags: c#, html, entity-framework, entity, formview

** Customizing Formviews**

I am trying to have dropdown and Checkboxes inside my Insert and Edit formViews. The FormView is being generated and is not hard coded and so I am having troubles finding a way to get a reference to the row since the ID's are generated in order to make drop downs and such. Is there another way that this is done?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" CodeBehind="Insert.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebAppPractice.Insert" %>

<asp:Content ID="headContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<asp:DynamicDataManager ID="DynamicDataManager1" runat="server" AutoLoadForeignKeys="true">
    <DataControls>
        <asp:DataControlReference ControlID="FormView1" />
    </DataControls>
</asp:DynamicDataManager>

<h2 class="DDSubHeader">Add new entry to table <%= table.DisplayName %></h2>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" EnableClientScript="true"
            HeaderText="List of validation errors" CssClass="DDValidator" />
        <asp:DynamicValidator runat="server" ID="DetailsViewValidator" ControlToValidate="FormView1" Display="None" CssClass="DDValidator" />

        <asp:FormView runat="server" ID="FormView1" DataSourceID="DetailsDataSource" DefaultMode="Insert"
            OnItemCommand="FormView1_ItemCommand" OnItemInserted="FormView1_ItemInserted" RenderOuterTable="false">
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <table id="detailsTable" class="DDDetailsTable" cellpadding="6">
                    <asp:DynamicEntity ID="InsertForm" runat="server" Mode="Insert" />
                    <tr class="td">
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>

        <asp:EntityDataSource ID="DetailsDataSource" runat="server" EnableInsert="true" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.DynamicData;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.Expressions;

namespace WebAppPractice
{
    public partial class Insert : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected MetaTable table;

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            table = DynamicDataRouteHandler.GetRequestMetaTable(Context);
            FormView1.SetMetaTable(table, table.GetColumnValuesFromRoute(Context));
            DetailsDataSource.EntityTypeFilter = table.EntityType.Name;
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Title = table.DisplayName;
        }

        protected void FormView1_ItemCommand(object sender, FormViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == DataControlCommands.CancelCommandName)
            {
                Response.Redirect(table.ListActionPath);
            }
        }

        protected void FormView1_ItemInserted(object sender, FormViewInsertedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Exception == null || e.ExceptionHandled)
            {
                Response.Redirect(table.ListActionPath);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The Front end Currently dispplay all the fields that are in the table with a text box next to it to input data.

Comment: Ok figured it out. This video showed me the magic. https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/ASP-NET-Site-Videos/how-do-i-change-how-my-fields-render